# AngularJS -> UI router, where to define controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

One can define controller for the state in ui router as `controller: 'MainController'`, but also this can be omitted, and instead controller can be defined in view (template url) as `ng-controller="MainController"`, what is the better practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better practice is to define the controller in the provider configuration (this also works with the core $routeProvider btw). It's best to keep your view as 'clean' as possible.

As @JBNizet added, this is also the only way for the router to inject the resolved dependencies into the controller (see the resolve property that you can pass into your route/state config)

Comment: But more importantly, that's the only way for the router to injected the `resolve`d dependencies to the controller.

Comment: Correct, I'll add it to to my answer

Comment: I have an Angular app in which my controller is defined by my routeProvider, however, in the associated view, I have references to scope member variables so the view still feels tightly coupled to my controller. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Drumbeg Referencing to scope member variables isn't wrong no

Comment: Cheers @NexusDuck. I realised a while back that my view is actually referencing a model, not a controller, which is more in line with how I picture MVC to work.

Comment: Could you explain the advantage to define the controller in the router instead of the view?  The view is tightly coupled to the route *anyways* b/c  it relies on the scope being set properly and the controllerAs being set properly.  It seems to break the L of LIFT b/c now I need to check the route to find out what controller a view is using!

Comment: @JBNizet Why do I need the router to resolve dependencies?  Couldn't I do that in the controller itself?

Comment: It makes the controller much easier to test (no need to mock http every time you create the controller in tests). It makes the view easier to implement (the view is never displayed with non-present data). It makes the user experience more natural (the view and URL changes only when the data is available, just like with a normal page load, instead of changing immediately, showing a page with no data until the data is obtained from the backend, and then displaying the data (if there is no error).